# Starting iaxmodem and faxmodem with upstart

Tags: centos, upstart, fax

How can I use Upstart to start `iaxmodem` and `faxgetty` when I have multiple modems? Centos 6.4 has a nice warning as listed below which incites me to believe the standard `inittab` lines will not work.

```
# inittab is only used by upstart for the default runlevel.
#
# ADDING OTHER CONFIGURATION HERE WILL HAVE NO EFFECT ON YOUR SYSTEM.
```

where I would normally put

```
IAX:2345:respawn:/path/to/iaxmodem ttyIAX
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a task which is started on change of runlevel to start a job for each `IAXModem` you want to start.  Then use a task to start a `faxgetty` for each started `iaxmodem` job.

IE:

```
init 3 -> start-iaxmodem ---> iaxmodem(ttyIAX0) -> start-faxgetty(ttyIAX0) -> faxgetty(ttyIAX0)
                          \-> iaxmodem(ttyIAX1) -> start-faxgetty(ttyIAX1) -> faxgetty(ttyIAX1)
```

`/etc/init/start-iaxmodems.conf`:

```
# This service starts the configured number of gettys.
start on stopped rc RUNLEVEL=[2345]

task

script
    for ttyIAX in /etc/iaxmodem/* ; do
        start iaxmodem TTY=`basename $ttyIAX`
    done
end script
```

`/etc/init/iaxmodem.conf`:

```
# This service maintains an iaxmodem on the sepcified device.
stop on runlevel [016]

respawn
instance $TTY
exec /usr/sbin/iaxmodem $TTY
```

`/etc/init/start-faxgettys.conf`:

```
# This service starts the configured number of faxgettys.
start on started iaxmodem
# this will run once per triggering iaxmodem instance
instance $INSTANCE

task

script
    # give it time to at least create the device
    /bin/sleep 1s
    start faxgetty TTY=$INSTANCE
end script
```

`/etc/init/faxgetty.conf`:

```
# This service maintains a faxgetty on the sepcified device.
# only stop when the stopping iaxmodem is this TTY
stop on stopping iaxmodem INSTANCE=$TTY

respawn
instance $TTY

exec /usr/sbin/faxgetty $TTY
```